On the natural map $\mathrm{Br}(R) \rightarrow \mathrm{Br}(S)$ of Brauer groups
$\DeclareMathOperator\Br{Br}$Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and let $\Br(R)$ be the Brauer group of $R$ as defined by Auslander and Goldman. Let $S$ be a commutative $R$-algebra, and consider the naturally induced homomorphism of Brauer groups $\Br(R) \rightarrow \Br(S)$.  This map has been studied by several authors for different choices of $S$, especially the case when $S=K$ is the quotient field  of $R$, beginning with Auslander and Goldman in their paper, followed by Auslander-Brumer (1968), Childs-Gorfinkel-Orzech (1975), and F. R. Demeyer (1975). As far as I know, these are the only works I have found. Demeyer also posed several questions for certain choices of $S$ at the end of his paper.
My question: Is there a more recent paper, book, or survey on this topic?
